# django get URL of ImageField

Tags: python, django

I have model with `ImageField`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

In `settings.py` initialized 2 variables:

```
MEDIA_ULR = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'skyeng/media')
```

in `views.py` get method:

```
    def get(self, request):
        query_set = Category.objects.all()
        items_data = [{
                'id': item.id,
                'name': item.name,
                'icon': item.icon.url} for item in query_set]

        return JsonResponse(items_data, safe=False)
```

It should return the response as in the example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Category1",
        "icon": "http://icon/url"
    }
]
```

So how i need change my code that `icon.url` in get method was like in response example?

Comment: Show how your response looks now please

Comment: `[`
    `{`
       ` "id": 15,`
        ` "name": "Category1",`
        `"icon": "/images/icon.webp"`
   ` }`
`]`

Comment: Please correct spelling of MEDIA_ULR in settings.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
request.build_absolute_uri(item.icon.url)
```

Comment: Please be more comprehensive: Where should that code go? Why does it fix the problem?